# Problem using rqt_image_view only image

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, plugin, rqt-image-view

I am a new user of ros2 humble. I used rqt_image_view sometimes with ros2 run and since one day I see only the image placeholder and the panel for the topic and else is away. I don't know how I did this and I hope somebody can help me. I found the work around solution that I use rqt direct and add the image_view plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Right click inside the image placeholder pane
- Uncheck the 'Hide toolbar' checkbox

[image]

Comment: thank you  I am so stupid 

Comment: No problem. Glad to help! Make sure you accept this answer so that people with the same question can refer to this :)